# See implicit exports from a Module

Tags: haskell, module, ghc, yesod, template-haskell

Quite surprisingly, I'm trying to fix a compilation warning `missing-export-lists` by adding explicitly the elements imported one by one for a specific module, but somehow there is something magical that this module is implicitly exporting that I can't find....

is it possible to retrieve what is exported implicitly with ghc ?

Here is an example of my issue, Yesod is generating some code with TH and quasiquotes :

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls             #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts           #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses      #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings          #-}
{-# LANGUAGE QuasiQuotes                #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell            #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies               #-}
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class  (liftIO)
import           Database.Persist
import           Database.Persist.Sqlite
import           Database.Persist.TH

share [mkPersist sqlSettings, mkMigrate "migrateAll"] [persistLowerCase|
Person
    name String
    age Int Maybe
    deriving Show
|]
```

Then let's say we use that generated code that way :

```
people <- selectList
    (       [PersonAge >. 25, PersonAge <=. 30]
        ||. [PersonName /<-. ["Adam", "Bonny"]]
        ||. ([PersonAge ==. 50] ||. [PersonAge ==. 60])
    )
    []
liftIO $ print people
```

Now I want to put share in a specific module and control precisely what I'm exporting from that code generated.

I don't know how it generates `PersonName` and `PersonAge` ! I don't how to specifically import these 2 types for example...

Comment: Could you give some more details on exactly which module, what's not being imported, etc.? The most helpful thing to supply would be an error message detailing exactly what is not in scope. It's very hard to answer this question without any of this information.

Comment: @bradrn I have added more information... Thx for the feedback..

Comment: Thanks for adding more info - it makes more sense now.